# How to dynamically use class names

Tags: php, class, object, zend-framework

How can I create a object of class in php, the twist is the middle part is changable according to the request ?

```
$myObj =  new Application_Model_XYZtable();
```

XYZ is the changeable part which depends on request by the user.

I tried this.

```
$myObj =  new Application_Model_ . $XYZ . table();
```

but not working.

Comment: You should not work with objects names, add a property inside the object with user choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use a string to define the whole name of the class.

[`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) can be used to determine if a class exists.

In example :

```
class testABCtest
{

}

class testDEFtest
{

}

$abc = 'abc';
$def = 'def';

$myclass1 = 'test' . $abc . 'test';
$myclass2 = 'test' . $def . 'test';
$myclass3 = 'IDontExists';

$obj1 = new $myclass1();
//          ^-------^--------+
$obj2 = new $myclass2(); //  +----Notice the whole names being variables (string)
//          ^-------^--------+
if (class_exists($myclass3))
{
    $obj3 = new $myclass3();
    var_dump($obj3);
}
else
    var_dump($myclass3 . " does not exist.");
var_dump($obj1, $obj2);
```

**Output**

```
C:\wamp64\www\New folder\test11.php:30:string 'IDontExists does not exist.' (length=26)
C:\wamp64\www\New folder\test11.php:33:
object(testABCtest)[1]
C:\wamp64\www\New folder\test11.php:33:
object(testDEFtest)[2]
```

Comment: Basically, I am working in Zend framework 1 and Application_Model define the path.
So if I am using this method then I am getting an error Application_Model_XYZtable not found in the test controller.

Comment: I'm sure you'll be able to easily adapt my *generic* answer to your case

Comment: Did you included the namespace?

Comment: I included proteced $_name = "db.Tbalename"; in my class. Are you asking about this?

Comment: No, I mean `use Application/Model/XYZtable;`

Comment: i am using this

$modelname = "Application_Model_DbTable_" . $this->ucfirstOprt . "MAPActivity()";

$mapActivityTbl = new $modelname();

Comment: please tell me is it ok ?

Comment: remove the `()` there `"Application_Model_DbTable_" . $this->ucfirstOprt . "MAPActivity()";`